# Intellij Plugin Development: toolWindow extension is blank when opened in different project windows

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

When I open multiple(3-4) projects in different intellij windows, my JSON  plugin tool window comes out blank. 
Here is my plugin.xml

```
<idea-plugin>
  <id>com.xxxxx.json.Editor</id>
  <name>JSON Editor</name>
  <version>1.5</version>
  <vendor email="xxxxxxxxxx" url="xxxxxxx">xxxxxx</vendor>

  <description><![CDATA[
      JetBrains IntelliJ IDE plugin for easy viewing and editing of currently opened JSON file in IDE using Tree Structure.
    ]]></description>

  <change-notes><![CDATA[
      Feature: Indentation changes - adding space after ':' char.
    ]]>
  </change-notes>

  <idea-version since-build="192.6"/>
  <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <toolWindow id="JSON Editor" anchor="right" factoryClass="JsonEditor" />
  </extensions>

  <actions>
  </actions>

</idea-plugin>
```

Here is the screenshot with the contents(buttons and Tree view) of the plugin JSON Editor tool window.

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the contents of the same toolWindow coming completely blank (which happens if multiple(3-4) projects are opened in different windows.)

[image]

Here is the code for createToolWindowContent method -

```
public class JsonEditor implements ToolWindowFactory {

    private JPanel mainContent;
    ....
    ....

    @Override
    public void createToolWindowContent(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull ToolWindow toolWindow) {
        this.project = project;
        ContentFactory contentFactory = 
        ContentFactory.SERVICE.getInstance();
        Content content = contentFactory.createContent(mainContent, "", false);
        toolWindow.getContentManager().addContent(content);
    }
}
```

How do I solve this issue? Also can I have different states of instances of the plugin extension opened in different?

Comment: How is your JsonEditor class implemented?

Comment: It implements ToolWindowFactory and overrides createToolWindowContent as -

`@Override
    public void createToolWindowContent(@NotNull Project project, @NotNull ToolWindow toolWindow) {
        this.project = project;
        ContentFactory contentFactory = ContentFactory.SERVICE.getInstance();
        Content content = contentFactory.createContent(mainContent, "", false);
        toolWindow.getContentManager().addContent(content);
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a different instance of `mainContent` every time the `createToolWindowContent` method is invoked since an AWT widget can only have one parent.

This method is invoked per IDE window so one window will "win".

So instead of writing `mainContent` write `createMainContentInstance()`. You can then get access to the details you need globally by working with the Project object for the current window which will be different between both windows.

Comment: How do I create and add multiple instances of mainContent? Could you please provide an example.

Comment: I don't know what's mainContent in your code, I lifted the name from there. But generally I'm assuming you did something like `mainContent = new JBScrollPane(new JTree(model))`... Instead of doing that and storing it in main content just convert that code to `private JComponent createMainContent() { return new JBScrollPane(new JTree(model)); }`